# How to make a password generator with javascript where i can toggle length, special characters, numbers, uppercase and lowercase

Tags: javascript, passwords, generator

```
function genPassword() {
    var chars = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz!@#$%^&*()ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    var passwordLength = prompt("Length:Enter a number between 8-128");
    var specialcharacters = prompt("Would you like special characters?");
    var numeric = prompt("Would you like numbers?");
    var upper = prompt("Would you like uppercase?");
    var lower = prompt("Would you like lowercase?");
    var password = "";
for (var i = 0; i <= passwordLength; i++) {
   var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length);
password += chars.substring(randomNumber, randomNumber +1);
  }
        document.getElementById("password").value = password;
}
```

When i click my generate btn i should get 5 prompts and the prompts should us that info to create the password like 8(for length), yes, no, no, yes.

Answer (score 0):

- Start with four different strings, one for each group of characters
- Start with empty `chars`
- For each "yes", append the appropriate character group to `chars`
- Then pick at random from the constructed `chars`.

Comment: var chars = "";
    var upperCase= "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    var lowerCase= "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    var number= "0123456789";
    var symbol= "!@#$%^&*()_+~\`|}{[]:;?><,./-="; like this?

Comment: Yep! (You could also use an object to store them, so you could deduplicate some code, but that is likely something for later.)

Comment: how do i append the yes's and make the chars pick from them?

Comment: `if (numeric === "yes") { chars += number; }`. You already know how to pick from `chars`.

Comment: if (upper === "yes") {
      chars += upperCase;
    } else{
(upperCase === no)
chars-=}
    if (lower === "yes") { chars += lowerCase; }
    if (numeric === "yes") { chars += number; }
    if (special === "yes") { chars += symbol; }

 var password = "";
for (var i = 0; i <= passwordLength; i++) {
   var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length);
password += chars.substring(randomNumber, randomNumber +1);
  }
        document.getElementById("password").value = password;
}= chars.substring(randomNumber, randomNumber +1); hows this?

Comment: The idea is correct. You have several errors there, but it will be a good exercise to debug them. For the future, please avoid extended code in comments, as it is very hard to read (anything over one or two statements is too much), and rather edit it in directly into the question.

Comment: i know one error is my else statement, but i cant figure out the correct syntax. i updated the code sorry about that, also my button wont work anymore and i don't get a password displayed anymore... sorry this is like my 4th day doing JavaScript haha i really appreciate the help

Comment: Don't edit the original code, because then the answers won't make sense. Add an additional section to your answer, like "EDIT: here is my updated code ...". Check your console for an error message (in Chrome it is F12, or Option-Command-J on my Mac; different computers and different browsers will have something similar). In particular, you don't have a variable called `no`, and `-=` is not a thing that strings can do, even if you specified the right hand side of it. That whole `else` is weird — and you did it correctly for the other three groups.

Comment: ah ok sorry new to stackoverflow. and ok ill try that out, so create a variable of no, var no = ""; or smth? so no else stament needed if i have a no variable?

Comment: No problem, everyone is new some day, this is why I am telling you. About `no`: you wanted to write `if (numeric === "no")`, but forgot the quotes. `no` without quotes is a variable, which you haven't defined before. But the whole `else` is not needed, as you simply don't need to add anything to `chars` if the answer is not `"yes"` — in particular, you don't need to subtract anything (and even if you did, `chars-=` would not work, for two different reasons).

Comment: yay it works!!! the only thing is i want to limit the characters to 8-128 and when i enter a value to the prompt it does +1 of what i entered EX: 3= aaaa any clues for that?